# Riemann integrability with partition points & Discontinuities of the function

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

I have a question about 'choosing partition points' for Riemann integrability.

For example,

> Let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function defined by $$f(x)\left\{\begin{array}{cc} 0, & x\in[0,1/2], \\ 1, & x\in(1/2,1]. \end{array}\right.$$
>   Then, for any given $\varepsilon>0$, choose a partition as $\left\{0,1/2-\varepsilon,1/2+\varepsilon,1\right\}$. I've always done this way that  'avoided discontinuities'.

But, i think a partition $\left\{0,1/2,1\right\}$ deduces the Riemann integrability of $f$ on $[0,1]$ as well.

Is it suitable choice to show the Riemann integrability for $f$?

Give some advice/comment. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you choose $\{0,1/2,1\}$, then you have an upper sum of $1/2$ and a lower sum of $0.$ So, the problem is a little more nuanced then that. You can use
$$\{0,1/2,1/2+\epsilon,1\}$$
though. This gives an upper sum of $1/2$, and a lower sum of $1/2-\epsilon$, which is enough to deduce Riemann integrability.

Comment: You're right. I have a miscomputation. But, i still wonder something. Then, as your partition, we can choice the partition points in set of discontinuities of any given function. right?

Comment: @Primavera, for finitely many discontinuity points, yes, that works out nicely. You can show if a function is continuous, then the upper and lower sums converge. Which you can exploit to show a function with finitely many partition points is Riemann integrable. It turns out that it actually holds for countable many discontinuities, but that requires a lot more work.